# Sumas y restas en una cadena

Tags: java, operador

Necesito implementar lo siguiente:

Entrada (una cadena):

```
5+45+100-125+5-10
```

Salida:

```
= 20
```

Aquí el código implementado sólo para números positivos:

```
String operacion="10+200+3000";
    int tam = operacion.length();
    String A[] = new String[100];
    int pos = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    String aux = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<tam ; i++)
    {
        if(operacion.charAt(i) == '+')
        {
            A[pos] = aux;
            pos++;
            aux = "";
        }
        else
        {
            aux = aux + operacion.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    A[pos] = aux;
    pos++;
    for(int i = 0; i<pos ; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("=  "+sum);
```

Salida

```
= 3210
```

El problema es que no consigo realizarlo para los negativos para hacer la operación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción sería almacenar los operadores, y en el último loop, realizar la operación respectiva:

```
   String operacion="5+45+100-125+5-10";      
   int tam = operacion.length();
    String A[] = new String[100];
    //Array para almacenar operadores.
    String operaciones[] = new String[100];
    int pos = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    String aux = "";

    //inicializa primer operador.
    operaciones[0] = "+";
    int index_operacion = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<tam ; i++)
    {
        if(operacion.charAt(i) == '+' || operacion.charAt(i) == '-')
        {
            A[pos] = aux;
            operaciones[index_operacion] = String.valueOf(operacion.charAt(i));
            pos++;   
            index_operacion++;
            aux = "";            
        }
        else
        {
            aux = aux + operacion.charAt(i);
        }        
    }
    A[pos] = aux;
    pos++;

    for(int i = 0; i<pos ; i++)
    {           
        //Determina la operación a realizar.         
        if(operaciones[i].equals("+")){
         sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(A[i]);    
        }else if (operaciones[i].equals("-")){
            sum=sum-Integer.parseInt(A[i]);            
        }         

    }
    System.out.println("=  "+sum);
```

de esta forma obtendrías un calculo correcto:

```
=  20
```

Comment: Gracias a todos, me han brindado mas maneras de pensar para resolver este tipo de problemas. Gracias nuevamente y saludos.

Comment: @RaulJ. Ese es un principio básico de la programación: Siempre hay más de un camino para llegar a algo.

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo en cuenta que los enteros tienen signo y que una resta no es más que la suma de un negativo, te planteo esta solución más compacta usando también expresiones regulares. Además controla si hubiera espacios entre los signos y los números como podrás ver en la entrada:

```
String operacion="5 + 45+100- 125 +5 -10";
//Quito los espacios por si los hubiera
String aux = operacion.replace(" ", "");
//Establezco el patrón 'NO número''Número'
String patron = "[^0-9][0-9]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patron);
Matcher m = p.matcher(aux);

int indiceActual = 0;
Integer suma = 0;
while (m.find(indiceActual+1)){//Muevo una posición para que no se repita
    int longitud = m.start();
    suma += Integer.valueOf(aux.substring(indiceActual, longitud));
    indiceActual = longitud;
}
//Sumo el último que no cumple la condición anterior
suma += Integer.valueOf(aux.substring(indiceActual));

System.out.println(operacion + " = " + suma);
```

La salida que obtenemos será:

> 5 + 45+100- 125 +5 -10 = 20

Answer (score 1):

Yo me crearía otro array para almacenar también los números negativos. Llamémosle B. Y también me crearía otro entero para controlar la posición.

```
String B[] = new String[100];
int posB = 0;
```

Y luego en la condición podemos utilizar la estructura `if-else if-else` de la siguiente manera:

```
if(operacion.charAt(i) == '+'){
     A[pos] = aux;
     pos++;
     aux = "";
}else if((operacion.charAt(i) == '-'){
     B[posB] = aux;
     posB++;
     aux = "";
}else{
     aux = aux + operacion.charAt(i);
}
```

La estructura `if-else if-else` funciona de la misma manera que un `if-else` aunque en este caso sería algo así como: "si cumple esta condición haz esto, si no la cumple comprueba si cumple esta otra condición y si la cumple, haz esto otro. Si ninguna de las dos comprobaciones se cumplen, haz esto otro".

Realmente podrás usar el valor de `aux` para las dos opciones ya que se vuelve a inicializar a vacío cada vez que encuentra un `+`  o un `-`.

Por último podrás realizar un bucle para restar los números negativos:

```
for(int i = 0; i<posB ; i++)
{
   sum=sum-Integer.parseInt(B[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mantener otro vector con los signos, ir almacenándolos a medida que recorres la cadena y finalmente realizar la operación, por ejemplo:

```
String operacion="10+200+3000-50-400";
    int tam = operacion.length();
    String numero[] = new String[100];
    String signo[] = new String[100];
    int pos = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    String aux = "";
    String ultimoSigno = "+";
    for(int i = 0; i<tam ; i++)
    {
        if((operacion.charAt(i) == '+')||(operacion.charAt(i) == '-'))
        {
            if (aux != "") {
                numero[pos] = aux;
                signo[pos] = ultimoSigno;
                pos++;
            }
            aux = "";
            ultimoSigno = operacion.charAt(i);
        }
        else
        {
            aux = aux + operacion.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    numero[pos] = aux;
    signo[pos] = ultimoSigno;
    pos++;
    for(int i = 0; i<pos ; i++)
    {
        if (signo[i]=='+') {
          sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
        } else {
          sum=sum-Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("=  "+sum);
```

He editado el código acá mismo, es probable que contenga algún error, pero creo que solo leyéndolo entenderás la idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sumar y restar los números que están en una cadena. En el ejemplo que pongo "5+45+100-125+5-10" el resultado es 20.

La forma más rápida y sencilla es mediante expresiones regulares que detecta cada número tanto positivo como negativo. Os dejo mi código.

```
String operation = "5+45+100-125+5-10";
String aux = operation.replace(" ", "");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]?[0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(aux);
Integer sum = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    sum += Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Saludos.

Comment: hola!, puedes explicar lo que hace tu código?

Comment: Mi código lo que hace es sumar y restar los números que están en una cadena. En el ejemplo que pongo "5+45+100-125+5-10" el resultado es 20. Con la expresión regular detecta cada número tanto positivo como negativo.

Comment: podrías agregarlo a tu respuesta :)

Comment: @Riaven ya lo he agregado a mi respuesta.